# How to set the 'placeholder' property in 'Input Field' component via c# script? (Image attached)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, components, placeholder

This is 'Input Field' component capture image.

Blue box is 'Placeholder' without linked.
I want to set this  value with my placeholder object

[image: my placeholder]

I mean 'my placeholder object' below.

In unity editor, I can set this using dragging 'my placeholder object' to blue box.

My question point is that how to get this via script.

[image]

```
InputField myInputField = myGameObject.AddComponent<InputField>();
myInputField.GetComponent<InputField>().placeholder = placeH01;
```

<< not working, type mismatch error with GameObject and UI.Graphic

Comment: Well you can look for tags, names, iterate children of objects. You just need to tell kt how it can find that object and be sure it found the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what `placeH01` is in your code but it sounds like it is a `GameObject` and you probably rather would want

```
// The GetComponent<InputField>() is quite redundant btw 
// myInputField already IS an InputField
myInputField.placeholder = placeH01.GetComponent<UI.Graphic>();
```

Comment: thanks. It works.placeH01 is GameObject

Comment: oops. comment edit time limited~
thank you very much. It works.
placeH01 is a GameObject for placeholder
There is one more question. 
GetComponent<UI.Graphic>();   this makes a error though already 'using UnityEngine.UI'
So I try 
GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Graphic>(); and it works.
What's wrong?

Comment: @bureaucoconut just use `.GetComponent<Graphic>();`